# Apprequest notification didn't lead to App Store as "iOS Native Deep Linking" is enabled

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on, facebook-app-requests

My question is simple. I sent a apprequest to someone who doesn't install my app and hopefully  they click it and are lead to App Store and then install my app.

My case is that my test user has received the notification in his Facebook iPhone app. He clicked it and the screen transferred and nothing happened. The screen jumped to home screen.

It's strange to me.

I've set "iOS Native Deep Linking" and "iOS SSO setting" enabled and a valid "iPhone App Store ID" as well, which I hope my test user would be led to download it.

I found the sentences in the document, 
"When someone taps a deep link in the Facebook for iPhone app, the user is immediately directed to your iOS app. If the app is not installed, the user is taken to the App Store to download your app."

I believe Facebook iPhone App should redirect the users to App Store as they tap on the notification. But it didn't and I don't know why.

Any suggestions? Many thanks.

Comment: Any test codes / links ?

Comment: Actually, I don't know which part should be posted here because I didn't see any wrong in code. So I guess maybe my concept is wrong or my setting with Facebook Dev Center were wrong.

I forgot to mention another case which is that the test user would be led to my app as my app has been installed after the test user clicked the notification.

Comment: Due to that, I think Facebook iPhone app successfully redirect the test user to my app. However, it fails to lead him to App Store as my app was not installed. 

I guess Facebook iPhone app maybe lack some essential data to do so. But I am not sure.